# For-loop return array value

Tags: arrays, for-loop, return-value, mustache

I'm trying to insert url for menu through mustache template. But just the first value is being returned for the array.

Or is this the return method wrong

```
      var main_menu_link =  ["main_dashboard.html", "#", "online_dashboard.html","index.html","#","#","#"]; 
      var url = "";
      var i;
      var url_link="";
      for(i = 0; i < main_menu_link.length; i++) {
       url += main_menu_link[i];
       return '<a href="'+ url  +'">' + text + '</a>';   
     }
```

[CodePen working here](http://codepen.io/DPK_RAO/pen/LxaRwo?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement has to be after the loop:

```
var main_menu_link =  ["main_dashboard.html", "#", "online_dashboard.html","index.html","#","#","#"]; 
var url = "";
var i;
var url_link="";
for(i = 0; i < main_menu_link.length; i++) {
  url += '<a href="'+ main_menu_link[i] +'">' + text + '</a>';  
}
return url;
```

Comment: this will give below result

Comment: <a href="main_dashboard.html#online_dashboard.htmlindex.html###"> Dashboard </a>

Comment: Edited to create seperate links for each element in the array, is this what you were after?

Comment: Now the li text is being displayed 5 times :) . Should I put that in a loop as well?

Comment: If you're creating a new list element for each item in the array then yes

Comment: Yeh that may be the case, to answer your question though the reason it was only outputting the first element of the array is because a return statement will exit the function immediately, you need to build a variable first and then return after the loop has finished. Hope you get your project sorted.

Comment: got the menu built from template, the formatting of the template itself was wrong, so the for-loop error was an additional error to an already wrong method :)  Thank you for correcting the loop issue.

Answer (score 0):

Correct template as below in-case it can be of use to someone else

```
var link_details = { "link_details" :[ 
{ main_menu: "Dashboard", main_menu_link: "dashboard.html" }, 
{ main_menu: "Analytics", main_menu_link: "#" }, 
{ main_menu: "System", main_menu_link: "system.html" } 
]}; 

var template = "<ul>{{#link_details}}<li><a href =\" {{main_menu_link}}\">{{main_menu}}</a></li>{{/link_details}}‌​</ul>"; 
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, link_details); 
document.write(html)
```